# Parsing data JS or Apex Controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

Is there a performance cost if we do business logic on the client JS side vs Apex server side ?

Let's say i have an Apex controller and a lightning component. on Page load, the JS controller is receiving a hashmap from Apex controller. Now i am doing additional business logic on the client and then rendering the data.

Which one is preferrable (Parsing the data in Apex or in JS) and why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, assuming you have sufficient bandwidth to transfer whatever data you need in a timely manner, client-side processing will be superior, as the client only has to handle its own data, while the server has to handle hundreds or even thousands of requests concurrently. This was true in the days of Visualforce, and is true today.

There is a tipping point where Apex processing would be superior in performance, but that involves a lot of data being distilled to a much smaller data set, and you have limited bandwidth available for data transfers. That is to say, certain mobile apps might benefit from server-side processing, but this is relatively rare. JavaScript simply has much better performance characteristics.

Do only as much processing on the server as necessary to arrange the data, then do the remaining processing on the client. However, if there's any business rules that must not be violated (e.g. required fields, etc), make sure you check those in your server logic. Clients can be compromised/modified by the users, so should be considered untrustworthy. Aside from that caveat, do as much client-side processing as you can.